# Unusual servo reaction

Tags: avr, servo

I'm using DIY pwm-generator based on attiny13 to control servo. Pulse cycle is 37 Hz, pulse width is ~540us - ~2400us. Servo rotates correctly but on stationary positions it's vibrates (gears try to move). It's connected to noise on top of the pulses. Noise has random period.
[image]

So, am i doing right that i'm always sending pwm signal to servo? Should i turn off signal after reaching necessary angle? Or it's just wrong pulse width?

Comment: If memory serves me right, repetition frequency for an RC servo is about 50Hz (Wikipedia states 40-200Hz), your 37Hz may be a little on the low side. Another important thing is: how large are your decoupling caps for the power supply lines of the servo? What's on the scope?

Comment: @jippie The same thing on 76 Hz. On the scope is pulse by which i control servo. You can see the noise on the top of the pulse. This noise is the reason of servo's gears vibrations. What is the story about decoupling capacitors? Never heard about them.

Comment: You're making a causation/correlation error. It's more likely that the motors are *causing* the "noise" due to the surge current when they energize. No position feedback system is perfect, so the servo is probably trying to constantly correct small errors that it isn't precise enough to actually ever achieve.

Comment: As I understand it, the servo PWM is specified as 540 us to 2400 us, but actual servos are perfectly happy with 1000-2000 us, lock-to-lock.  If the servo has hit its stop, and you try to tell it to go farther, it will probably try to drive harder into the stop, and that will almost certainly try to put spikes on the power bus.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a standard size servo, put about 200 uF across the servo power leads, as close to the servo as possible.  Put something similar across your control circuit.

Servos draw a LOT of power when they move.  They draw even more in the startup spike when they start to move.  This puts nasty glitches on your power bus, and those glitches CAN get back into your control circuit.

Yes, this answer *IS* written in my personal blood, thank you for asking...

Comment: I use TowerPro MG946R. On move without physical load it consumes 400mA. Thanks for answer, i'll try.

Comment: @r_spb, my playing with this was a long time ago, using a 555, a transistor inverter, and a Tower Hobbies Royal Titan Standard.  You might need more than 200 uF to tame your servo.  Also, see my new comment about pulse widths, above.